# Custom PeriodIndex (Python / Pandas equivalent to SAS INTNX)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a SAS background and I am new to Python. I would like to how to use PeriodIndex in a similar way that we use SAS intervals. This is my problem:
We have an official interest rate that is published more or less monthly. This interest rate is valid until the next one is published. My objective is to obtain for any given date (let’s call it reference_date), the valid interest rate for that day.

### For instance:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'publication_date': ['2012-07-03',  '2012-08-02',   '2012-09-04',   '2012-10-02',   '2012-11-03',   '2012-12-04' ] ,
                'interest_value': [1.219,   1.061,  0.877,  0.74,   0.65,   0.588] })
   interest_value publication_date
0           1.219       2012-07-03
1           1.061       2012-08-02
2           0.877       2012-09-04
3           0.740       2012-10-02
4           0.650       2012-11-03
5           0.588       2012-12-04
```

In SAS I would create a custom interval, (let’s call it INTEREST_INTERVAL). It would contain the periods (that is the BEGIN date and END date) for which each interest is valid. For the example above, the interval would be the following:

```
BEGIN    END         
03JUL12  01AUG12    
02AUG12  03SEP12    
04SEP12  01OCT12    
02OCT12  02NOV12    
03NOV12  03DEC12
```

Than I would use the INTNX function. INTNX allow to “move” a number of periods up and down my custom interval and then return either the period start date or end date.
In this case,  I would use:

```
pub_date =  INTNX(INTEREST_INTERVAL, reference_date, 0 , 'BEGINNING')
```

This will instruct to add zero intervals to the reference date and return the start date of the interval. 
For instance, if the reference_date is equal to '2012-09-02', the above function would return 02AUG12. Then I would do a direct lookup (dictionary search) on the 'publication_date' / 'interest_value' table to obtain the valid interest rate for that day.

I thought that thru Panda´s PeriodIndex, with a second column for interest rate value, I would be able to do something similar, but I could not find out:

- How to create custom PeriodIndex?
- From a specific date value (reference_date) return the row corresponding to the period it falls into?

How would be the best way to do this in Pandas.

Thanks,

B.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is actually more python than pandas. Think about it this way, if your date is after the last date in the list you want the last rate, if it's not then if it is after the one before you want the one before and again and again. this is the logic the following code uses (I hope). Let me know if it works for you.

```
df.publication_date = pd.to_datetime(df.publication_date)

def get_interest_by_date(date):
    for date_interest in zip(df.publication_date.values[::-1], df.interest_value.values[::-1]):
        if date>=date_interest[0]:
            return float(date_interest[1])
```

and testing:

```
get_interest_by_date(pd.to_datetime('2012-10-05'))
```

> 0.74

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The code works, but I was hoping to use something more direct. I have to look up several interest rates, over the span of many years for several hundred thousand records. 
If I cannot create a custom periodindex and directly match a date to the correct period record, I will probably just create a daily dataframe, repeating all data for the duration of each interest rate (except the lookup date) and do a direct index lookup on the date. It is not elegant, but it is probably fast.